# mysql connector 32 vs 64 bit, yum update on CentOS

Tags: centos6, mysql-connector

I have 32 bit apps running on a 64 bit CentOS box.  Right now, for whatever reason, I have both the 32 bit and 64 bit mysql connector odbc drivers installed.  Since my apps are 32 bit, I have some questions:

1. Can I safely uninstall the 64 bit driver to avoid confusion?
2. Do I NEED to uninstall the 64 bit driver, or will it be used by the 32 bit apps?  Yes, I will be shocked if it will be used by the 32 bit apps, but asking just to be 100% sure.
3. What repo do I use to get 32 bit updates via YUM?

I am trying to update my system and, of course, it is failing because of the two architectures, thus this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is a partial answer based on what I found out:

1. I believe I did uninstall 64 bit and did not need it.  In my case, since it was an isolated system, easier to just try it and see.  Not much help, but better than nothing.
2. 32 bit apps should use 32 bit libs, based on odbc setup.  Did not really test it, but seemed rather obvious.
3. As per my question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55908696/yum-repository-setup-for-both-32-bit-and-64-bit-mysql-connector), just added a repo called "mysql-connectors-community-32" that is a virtual duplicate of "mysql-connectors-community".