# yum repository setup for both 32 bit and 64 bit, mysql connector

Tags: mysql, centos6, yum, mysql-connector

In my repository setup, I have the following:

```
[mysql-connectors-community]
name=MySQL Connectors Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

Because my machine is a 64 bit machine, my basesearch is x86_64 ( see below yum-debug-dump output ):

```
yum-debug-dump version 1
%%%%SYSTEM INFO
  uname: 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64, x86_64
  rpm ver: RPM version 4.8.0
  python ver: 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 18 2016, 15:13:37) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)]
%%%%YUM INFO
  arch: ia32e
  basearch: x86_64
  releasever: 6
  yum ver: 3.2.29
  enabled plugins: fastestmirror,presto
  global excludes:
.... ( entire output NOT included )
```

Is it possible to make another repository called, say, "mysql-connectors-community-i386" and with the following configuration so I can support both:

```
[mysql-connectors-community]
name=MySQL Connectors Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/el/6/i386/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

Yes, the URL is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually does work.  It is kind of klunky, and I assume there are better ways, but it works and helped me get around some issues.

Edit, for clarity, here are my connector repos to get both 64 bit and 32 bit on my machine:

```
more /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo
...
[mysql-connectors-community]
name=MySQL Connectors Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

[mysql-connectors-community-32]
name=MySQL Connectors Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/el/7/i386/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```